# Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '*' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having problems when I add an item to a CardList and try to display it using a Carousel. The item is added to the list but when I try to see it through the Carousel the error is shown :

I/flutter (12255): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '*' was called on null.

I have tried to not leave anything uninitialized as I have read in similar cases regarding this issue, but it doesn't help.

you can check my code here on my Github profile: https://github.com/varamsky/notes

And this is an image of the emulator screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlBbk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kumar
I see your code and find the problem. 
In file `todoCard.dart` in line 93 have this:

```dart
child: Text('${(percent*100).toInt()}%'),
```

This operation in the string (percent*100) not is valid because, for some reason, the `percent` is null. 
You need to verify if `percent` is null.

PS: In next time, please place the code in answer, to facilitate a response.

PS2: I make a pull request to add a complete gitignore in your repository. This makes the repository easier to clone and work with him :D

A hug

Comment: Thank you very much, Matias. It worked fine when I ensured that `percent` is not null. Regarding your suggestion to place code in the answer, I thought that it wasn't possible to answer this question without the complete project as I wasn't sure which part has the error precisely, so I referred the entire project :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I solved this problem while when I added:

**textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,** below the Row
check ----

[image]